# Giving 404 error in web site ? Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i created a site and place the code in my domain [using filezilla i upload the my pages in my domain ]. i place my folder which contain the code in domain like
BusinessEntity Folder, BusinessLayer Folder, DataAccess Layer and my code Folder. my web.config is my code folder. but when i type my url it is giving 404 error. Can you help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

404 - Not Found error. Some resource can't be obtained. Open Fiddler or any other web debugger and check what request return 404 error. After that check existing a resource corresponding to Url

Answer (score 0):

Please check all these things are done properly

1. Publish the project from your local machine (using visual studio)
2. Upload the published project to the server.
3. Create a virtual directory in iis (in the server)
4. Map the virtual directory to the project folder (means select the physical directory as the project folder)
5. Do the necessary configuration changes (conection strings or appsettings)
6. Give write permission for the upload folder and error folder (If you use any)

Checkout http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html